# How to fix "No such file or directory" during gitlab-ci run

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have just configured the gitlab-ci with a runner, and run the template `bash` ci tasks as:

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
# see https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html for all available options

# you can delete this line if you're not using Docker
#image: busybox:latest

before_script:
  - echo "Before script section"
  - echo "For example you might run an update here or install a build dependency"
  - echo "Or perhaps you might print out some debugging details"

after_script:
  - echo "After script section"
  - echo "For example you might do some cleanup here"

build1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Do your build here"

test1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Do a test here"
    - echo "For example run a test suite"

test2:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Do another parallel test here"
    - echo "For example run a lint test"

deploy1:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Do your deploy here"
```

But the job has failed:

[image]

And I logged into the runner machine and found there is only a ${projectname}.tmp folder under the desired location

[image]

did I miss something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

finally found this was a bug with gitlab-runner and Debian/Buster, comment out the `.bash_logout` file at `/home/gitlab-runner` will fix this

Here is [the discussion](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/4092) of this issue in case of helping other who meet with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but my issue was caused by `cdebootstrap`

To fix the issue I used:

```
stable ./debian-minbase http://deb.debian.org/debian/
```

Hope this answer is useful.

You can also use: `sudo find / -name "mk-prebuilt-images.sh"`

It will end up finding:

```
/usr/lib/gitlab-runner/mk-prebuilt-images.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried to add `cdebootstrap` with `apt-get install cdebootstrap` but the problem still exists